# Expected value of $\max(x,y) $ given that $x<y$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

What is the expected value of $\max(X,Y)$ given that $X<Y$? $X$ and $Y$ are independent and exponential random variables.

Comment: Hint: $\mathsf E(\max(X,Y)\mid X<Y) = \mathsf E(Y\mid X<Y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(\max(X,Y)\mid X<Y) & = \mathsf E(Y\mid X<Y)
\\[1ex] & = \int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty y\, f_{X,Y}(x,y\mid X<Y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y
\\[1ex] & = \int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty y\cdot \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathbf 1_{x<y}}{\mathsf P(X<Y)}\operatorname d x\operatorname d y
\\[1ex] & = \frac{\int_0^\infty\int_0^y y\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y}{\mathsf P(X<Y)}
\\ & \ddots
\end{align}$$

The rest is left to you.

---

PS:

$\mathbf 1_{x<y}$ is an **indicator function**; having the value of one when the subscript is true, and zero elsewhere.

$$\mathbf 1_{x,y}=\begin{cases}1 & : x<y \\ 0 & : \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

Comment: @sfk It's an **indicator function**, a piecewise function equal to one when the subscript is true, or zero otherwise. $$\mathbf 1_{x<y} \mathop{:=} \begin{cases}1 & : x<y \\ 0 & : \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: $f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathbf 1_{x<y} = f(X=x\cap Y=x\cap X<Y)$

Comment: what does conditional expectation mean if one it's not conditioning with respect to a sigma algebra?

Comment: @Ant It means one is conditioning a random variable, $X$, with respect to *an event*, $\mathsf A$, in *classical probability theory*, where: $$\Bbb E(X\mid \mathsf A) = \frac{\Bbb E(X \mathbf 1_{\mathsf A})}{\Bbb P(\mathsf A)}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Ah, I see, thank you. Basically we are taking expectation wrt $Q(\Lambda) = P(\Lambda \mid A)$. What do you mean with *classical probability theory*? As opposed to.. ? Thanks :-)

Comment: @Ant As opposed to *modern probability theory*, which is based on *measure theory*.

Comment: @GrahamKemp What if X and Y is not independent? Does this change the result?

Comment: @user2396444 Not if you know the *joint probability density function*.